# Ansible, distribute a list to other list

Tags: list, loops, split, ansible, distribute

I'm trying to do this with ansible:

I have multiple "fruits" and want to distrubute to multiple kids:

```
  - vars:
      kids:
      - John
      - Shara
      - David
      fruits:
      - Banana
      - Mango
      - Orange
      - Peach
      - Pineapple
      - Watermelon
      - Avocado
      - Cherries
```

Desidered result, something like this:

```
John:
- Banana
- Peach
- Avocado


Shara:
- Mango
- Pineapple
- Cherries

David:
- Orange
- Watermelon
```

I tried with zip, zip_longest, list, but no way.

```
ansible.builtin.debug:
  msg: "{{ item | zip(['a','b','c','d','e','f']) | list }}"
loop:
  - John
  - Shara
  - David
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(kids|zip(_values)) }}"
      vars:
        _batch: "{{ fruits|length|int / kids|length|int }}"
        _values: "{{ fruits|batch(_batch|float|round)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    David:
    - Avocado
    - Cherries
    John:
    - Banana
    - Mango
    - Orange
    Shara:
    - Peach
    - Pineapple
    - Watermelon
```

---

Q: *"**Have more than 4 kids**"*

A: For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    kids:
    - John
    - Shara
    - David
    - Alice
    - Bob
    fruits:
    - Banana
    - Mango
    - Orange
    - Peach
    - Pineapple
    - Watermelon
    - Avocado
    - Cherries
    - Apple
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ dict(kids|zip(_values)) }}"
      vars:
        _batch: "{{ fruits|length|int / kids|length|int }}"
        _values: "{{ fruits|batch(_batch|float|round)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: _dict
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    Alice:
    - Avocado
    - Cherries
    Bob:
    - Apple
    David:
    - Pineapple
    - Watermelon
    John:
    - Banana
    - Mango
    Shara:
    - Orange
    - Peach
```

Comment: I discover that when have more than 4 kids, the set_fact only distribute the fruits between the first 4 kids. Why?

Comment: Ok, in the batch filter I need the operation between fruits % kids, not the number of kids.

Comment: Good catch! The length of the batches must be the division of the fruits by the kids. I fixed the answer. Make sure there are enough fruits :)

Comment: Great!
I was trying to fix it, but you have been faster.
Thanks again!!!!